# Sharing the data or context between two different tomcat server?

Tags: spring, jsf, tomcat7

There is scenario in my project where I have to share the data from one project to another both the project are running on different server.

I am using JSF and Spring in my project where spring use only for Data base things.

I want to know there is a any way like cross context to share the data or context of two different server.

I am using tomcat 7.0.67, spring 3.3.0 and jsf 1.2

Comment: Hm, this question is strange as it already contains the answer: a database.

Comment: Data that I have to share is not store into the Data base and I can not store that data into data base..

Comment: Then next step is to fix that "can not" so you can do it. Do note that the data store does not necessarily need to be a SQL based RDBMS. Anything which can be accessed by both sides is perfectly doable, from a plain text file to a web service.

Comment: Thanks for advice I will try this approach also

Answer (score 0):

I have achieve sharing data between to different server using the restful web service